# Result return more 0s digits after point in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, case

I try to show `Freight with tax`, but result have more 0s digits after point:

[image]

Here is the code to be able to reproduce the situation:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Freight MONEY,
);
DROP TABLE Orders
SELECT * FROM Orders
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
(10270, 136.54),
(10271, 4.54),
(10272, 98.03),
(10273, 76.07);

-- code need fix(sol1)
SELECT OrderID,
       Freight,
       CASE
           WHEN Freight >= 100 THEN '10%' ELSE '5%'
           END AS tax,
       CASE
           WHEN Freight >= 100 THEN Freight * 1.1 ELSE Freight * 1.05
       END AS [Freight with tax]
FROM Orders

-- Code return result i need(sol2)
WITH _TAX
AS (SELECT OrderID,
           Freight,
           CASE
               WHEN Freight >= 100 THEN '10%' ELSE '5%'
           END AS tax
    FROM Orders)
SELECT *, Freight * (SUBSTRING(tax, 0, DATALENGTH(tax)) + 100) / 100 AS [Freight with tax]
FROM _TAX;
```

Result i want:

[image]

I want know to fix in my sol1 or any way can return result i need. Thank you.

Comment: The rules for how precision and scale end up after multiplying decimals are [a bit complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql), but are designed to ensure the column can hold the results of any outcome correctly. If you need less precision, cast the final result.

Comment: CASE statement seem alway return in `decimal(18,6)`  but i need result show exacly digit after point without 0s so i can't using `ROUND` in here

Comment: This will always need rounding when you decide to use only 2 decimals.  For example: `SELECT CAST(2.0/3 as DECIMAL(8,2))`  (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/pQldsRof))

Comment: That's a display issue then. Multiplying a `MONEY` by `1.05` needs up to 6 digits of precision in the worst case, meaning you will at least need that much precision. Management Studio chooses to format `MONEY` without trailing zeros, but not `DECIMAL`, but again: that's just how it chooses to display things. You can cast the final result to `MONEY`, but you do run the risk of rounding in that case. If you really have to you can use `FORMAT` (`SELECT FORMAT($98.9877 * 1.05, '#.######')`) but be aware that it's 1) slow and 2) turns your value into a string so you can't calculate with it anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I seem to able fix it in `CASE` statement by replace `Freight * 1.1` by `Freight * 110/100`.

Comment: This changes the calculation be entirely `MONEY` based, but you introduce intermediate rounding this way. `SELECT $0.9999 * 1.1` is `1.09989`, but `SELECT $0.9999 * 110 / 100` is `1.0998`, which is incorrect compared to the actual rounded result you'd get with `SELECT CAST($0.9999 * 1.1 AS MONEY)`, which is `1.0999`. So of all your options that's probably the worst one, in terms of keeping the results predictable.

Comment: My mistake, when i using `CAST` to convert money to float `SELECT CAST($0.9999 AS float)*110/100`, it was return same value with `SELECT $0.9999 * 1.1`. Is there anything wrong when i using it?

Comment: Well yes, in that `FLOAT` is binary floating-point and thus imprecise with regards to decimal calculations. This starts to matter if your `MONEY` gets big enough: `SELECT CAST($10000000000.3335 AS FLOAT) * 1.1` <> `SELECT $10000000000.3335 * 1.1` <> `SELECT CAST($10000000000.3335 * 1.1 AS MONEY)`. Honestly, the best solution is to give values to the client with sufficient precision to hold the result and let it choose how to display, or (if 4 digits are enough because this is a monetary value) to round but only at the last step. Don't introduce precision-reducing hacks to save typing.

Comment: thanks and sorry to bother you, it's part of my exercise so i need to make sure the result is the same as the sample result.